# Can I import a specific vssettings file when launching SSMS?

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sql-server-2014

In the interest of disambiguating between when I am connecting to non-production and production, I utilize vssettings for a specific theme in Management Studio (fire-and-brimstone style when in prod, calming blues in non-prod).

Previously our non-production access was via one account, and our production access was via a more restricted account.  With that method I was able to set a theme for each account one time and all was well.  Now all access is using the elevated account.

Is there a way to tell SSMS at launch time to use a specific theme?  Or a programmatic way to do this without going through "Tools > Import and Export Settings" every time?  I'm using the SQL 2014 version of SSMS.

Thanks.

Comment: Since having 2 accounts worked for you, why not continue using 2 accounts, even if the permissions are identical?

Comment: It wasn't my decision to make.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't played with themes, but you can set per-connection properties, including the color of the connection info bar at the bottom of the query tab. And these settings are saved.

If you have a query tab open, go to "Change Connection" (either the button in the button bar, or via the **Query** menu, top item should be **Connection >**, and when it pops up the "Connect to a Database Engine" dialog, click on the **Options >>** button. Go to the **Connection Properties** tab and the bottom option is **Use custom color:**. Check the check-box for it and click on the **Select...** button on the right.

Just use different colors for the different servers/environments.

---

Technically speaking, there *is* a means of programmatically interacting with SSMS: write a plug-in / extension. I will list some resources below that deal with this topic. I have not tried it yet myself, but it *seems* as though it might be a lot of effort for a one-time config update. On the other hand, if SSMS will not record the setting for 100, let alone 400, separate connections (not sure what the limit is), then maybe this would be worth the effort.

- [The art and science of creating SSMS 2012 add-ins – Part 1 – Laying the Foundation](http://solutioncenter.apexsql.com/the-art-and-science-of-creating-ssms-2012-add-ins-part-1-laying-the-foundation/) (this is a 3 part series with links to parts 2 and 3 towards the bottom; towards the bottom of part 3 are 6 links to other resources, the first of which I will duplicate as the next item)
- [How to write own add-in for SSMS 2012 (Final release version)](http://www.ssmsboost.com/create-own-ssms-2012-add-in-sample-code-with-download)
- [Automation and Extensibility Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1xt0ezx9.aspx) (for Visual Studio, but it should be very similar with SSMS, at least as of SQL Server 2012)

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Yeah, I do that too.  Healthy paranoia, right?  You can set that globally, which falls into the same boat as a vssettings theme.  And I have 400+ servers to maintain, so I'm hoping there's a programmatic way to do it.  If no one else chimes in I'll take what you have an answer.

Comment: @ZabadakGalorex I would highly doubt that there would be a programmatic way to do this. This is not something within SQL Server but user settings stored locally via Management Studio. I didn't see anything in the `.vssettings` file. I checked the registry but didn't see my stuff there either, unless it was serialized as a blob of stuff in which case that wouldn't help either.

Comment: @ZabadakGalorex Well, there _might_ be a slight chance of doing this, but I can't get very far as I think my system is a little hosed. But check out the SSMS ["Command Window"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645935.aspx). I can't get it to work, but I can get an "Immediate" window by going to **Debug** | **Windows** | **Immediate**. In there, I can enter in just `>Query.ChangeConnection` and it will open the **Change Database Connection** dialog. If we can figure out how to get to that specific connection property, you might could paste in 400 lines ;-). So, getting closer perhaps?

Comment: @ZabadakGalorex Hey, I just had another thought and added an update to my answer (below the line) about a way to programmatically interact with SSMS, though just not sure about level of effort required.

Comment: Thanks for the extra effort, very cool.  I personally don't work with plug-in/extensions but I'll ask around.  In the mean time if you open two SSMS windows, then set the theme in each, it seems to 'hold' that for the duration the window is open.  A bit more manual work each morning.